# PHP-How can I display my dropdown with all options?

Tags: dropdown

I display a dropdown but I would like to see all options when I load the page.

I sought but I didn't find to do this.

It is possible ?

I work with PHP langague.

```
<p> Dropdown :<br /> <select name="dropdown"> <option disabled selected>Sélectionner</option> <option value="1">Choix1</option> <option value="2">Choix2</option> </select> </p>
```

Comment: Please be very specific.

Comment: please edit you question. What kind of project do you have? Whicht progamming language are you using?

Comment: I work with PHP. ``<p>
Dropdown :<br />
<select name="dropdown">
  <option disabled selected>Sélectionner</option>
  <option value="1">Choix1</option>
  <option value="2">Choix2</option>
</select>
</p>``